# How do I create an outline for my SKSpriteNode around the png texture in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am making a game in Swift(SpriteKit) and when the character in the game picks up a power-up, I want him to get an outline in purple so the player can see that his power-up is ready to use. I want the outline to hug all the curves of the player exactly. Is there any way to draw an outline around a sprite node that isn't a basic shape(like circle or square) but to outline a complex shape?

Here is an example of a shape similar to my sprite node:
[image]

And here is another example of the player with the visual outline that I want to add in SpriteKit(I just sketched it but I want it to be exact obviously):
[image]

They player also has his legs animating by flipping through an atlas of the animation, and preferably the outline would stay around the legs when the walking animation is happening. Is this possible?

To be clear, I just want an outline for visual purposes, so the player knows their "power up" shield is active so if they get hit it won't damage them.

Comment: "Is there any way to do this?"  What is THIS?

Comment: @ElTomato Sorry just edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: You can create a node with `SKShapeNode` where you have a stroke property.  So use `SKShapeNode`, if necessary, with `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: I think you've got four reasonable choices... 1) Special power-up versions of the different poses in the animation.  2) Do some automated image processing of the poses, like a blur and setting of the color, add those in your atlas, and then when powered-up use an stack of two sprites with the regular character in front of a background power-up.  3) Make a shader for doing the blur and recoloring as in #2, then stack the regular image on top of image+shader.  4) If the character coloring is simple enough (e.g. a b&w character) you can make a shader just to add the outline with no stacking.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dabbled with SpriteKit for a few years, and if memory serves me correctly perfect collision detection while animating is not available out of the box.

After checking the documentation I see that SKPhysicsBody has a `init(texture:size:)` initializer. This should at least get you a bit closer.

This [guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/shaping_a_physics_body_to_match_a_node_s_graphics) from Apple is probably worth a read. (Pixel perfect collision detection is expensive).

Comment: Hey, sorry I don't think I made myself clear on my original post. I am actually just wondering how to add an outline for visual purposes. Just edited my original post to make it more clear. Thanks for the response!